# Initialize half float texture with a copy of another half float texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

I want to copy a texture onto another to initialize its values. Unfortunately, being a half float texture, I cannot use `glClear` (at least I couldn't find a way of clearing with a number like 10e10). So I tried:

```
glDrawArrays [...]

glFinish();
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _bestSADTexture);
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED_EXT, 0, 0, width, height, 0);
_bestSADInitialized = YES;
glActiveTexture(0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

The texture I want to copy acts as FBO color attachment to the framebuffer where I just rendered to. It's not working though as the texture remains black (checking the contents using the XCode OpenGL tools). Is there anything I am missing? Any other way I can initialize the texture with big values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the docs for the extension that allows half float textures ([GL_OES_texture_half_float](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt)) I confirmed that `glCopyTexImage2D` doesn't work with these textures.

> 3. Should CopyTexImage2D, CopyTexSubImage{2D|3D} be supported for textures
>          with half-float and float channels?
>
>    ```
>    RESOLUTION: No.
>    ```